# spring jpa projection nested bean

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

is it possible to have a projection with nested collection with Spring JPA?

I have the following 2 simple entity (to explain the problem)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;    
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Address> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;    
    private String city;
    private String street;        
}
```

Is it possible to have a projection of Person with following attributes filled in ? {person.name, address.city}

I might be wrong in semantics of word Projection. but the problem is what i need to achieve. Maybe it is not possible with Projection, but is there another way to achieve the end goal? Named Entity graph perhaps ?

P.S. please suggest a solution for Spring JPA not Spring Jpa REST
thanks in advance

Comment: [Closed Projection does not work with @EntityGraph](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1814)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, **Entity Graphs** serve this exact purpose - control field loading.

Create entity graphs dynamically from the code or annotate target entities with **Named Entity Graphs** and then just use their name.

Here is how to modify your `Person` class to use Named Entity Graphs:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "persion.name.with.city", 
               attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "addressList", subgraph = "addresses.city"), 
               subgraphs = @NamedSubgraph(name = "addresses.city", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("city")))
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;    
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Address> addressList;
}
```

And then when loading your person:

```
EntityGraph graph = em.getEntityGraph("person.name.with.city");

Map hints = new HashMap();
hints.put("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);

return em.find(Person.class, personId, hints);
```

The same applies for queries, not only `em.find` method.

Look [this tutorial](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/) for more details.

Comment: @Arterm, Is it possible to create a hierarchy with Entity Graph?
For Instance
AddressMini (Entity Graph for Address with only city loaded)
Person -> {name, List<AddressMini>} loaded
Cat -> {name, List<AddressMini>} loaded

To say, referring a namedEntityQuery inside another namedEntityGraph for nested Entities

Comment: @user4772933 that's exaclty what I do in my example. I use `subgraph` to define what fields addresses (that are inside the person) should have. Never create additional classes for this (like `AddressMini`), just tell JPA what fields you want to be loaded by using Entity Graphs.

Answer (score -2):

I think that that's not usual scenario of Data JPA usage. But you can achieve your goal with pure JPQL:

```
SELECT a.street, a.person.name FROM Address a WHERE …
```

This solution has 2 drawbacks:

1. It forces you to have bidirectional relationship Address ←→ Person
2. It returns List

Another solution (and that's preferred JPA way) is to create DTO like this:

```
class MyPersonDTO {
  private String personName;
  private List<String> cities;
  public MyPersonDTO(String personName, List<Address> adresses) {
    this.personName = personName;
    cities = adresses
      .stream()
      .map(Address::getCity)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

And the execute JPQL query like this:

```
SELECT NEW package.MyPersonDTO(p.name, p.addressList) FROM Person p WHERE …
```

Return type will be `List<MyPersonDTO>` in that case.

Of course you can use any of this solutions inside `@Query` annotation and it should work.

Comment: The problem with that is you CANNOT have a constructor item that is a multi-valued field. See the JPQL BNF `"constructor_item ::= single_valued_path_expression | scalar_expression | aggregate_expression | identification_variable"`

Comment: @NeilStockton but JPA provider can provide custom possibilities. i.e. hibernate allows that.

Comment: So your code becomes totally unportable; good luck, you're on your own.

Comment: @NeilStockton how often do you migrate from one provider to another? In my 9-year JPA career I didn't even one time.